# When compressing a file on command prompt with RAR command, how to stop the process without cancelling it?

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, winrar

I used the following command:

```
rar a -m2 file.rar *.xml \\myroute\
```

I want to stop the process on the file that have already been processed i.e. using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will cancel the process but not finish it.

Another question (related); is there a key combination to show the process as percentage or else?

Comment: Just wanted to ask, is using the command-line rar.exe a necessity? If you simply use winrar.exe instead in your command above, you'll get a GUI dialog with a progress bar displaying the percentage and current compression ratio, that allows you to pause and resume as required. (I'm not posting this as an answer yet since I'm not sure it's suitable for your use case.)

Comment: Hi @Karan I was trying to save time and processing (also using remote server files) that's why I wanted to use command prompt instead of GUI

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How is using rar.exe instead of winrar.exe saving time or 'processing' for you exactly? You'd be using the exact same command line, except substituting rar.exe with winrar.exe, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Sysinternals' Process Explorer (free), and look for your RAR process in the process list. There you can suspend and resume the process, and also see I/O indicators and totals that can help you find about the progress (however it won't be like WinRAR's progress bar)

Comment: Thanks for the Tool, I didn't know it. But I'm looking on something more specific like in Unix clicking Ctrl-Something to show progress.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to wrap your rar command in a script (PowerShell maybe) where you would calculate the number of files to process first (thereby giving you a way of establishing a completion percentage) and then add one file at time to the archive, reporting on completion after each and giving scope for a key press to finish the operation. But that will be much slower.

Comment: This sounds like a complex process. I was thinking something easier, just like in Unix, where you click Ctrl+Something and gives you the progress.

Comment: It is complex. Can Unix also stop an archive process halfway through but still leave a valid archive file?